# Unit of Work and returning newly created Object ID's, or custom Response objects

Tags: unit-of-work

Unit of Work is a great pattern, and I've been incorporating it into our Repository CUD operations...

the one thing I see as a drawback is the inability to return back to the calling code the ID(s) (or maybe a response DTO(s)) of multiple objects associated with the Unit of Work when it comes to Create() methods.

For example, let's say I have a Customer and an Order object. I create new transient objects in my calling code, add them through a .Create() method for the Unit of Work, and then Commit the Unit of Work.

Although my objects are persisted properly to the database, I am not calling each object's Repository.Create() from my consuming code, the Unit of Work is, so I don't really have a chance to send any information back to the consuming code as it relates to each specific object.

Any ideas? Can (or a better question, SHOULD) the Unit of Work be extended to return some type, maybe a custom object that could have the types of objects with their new ID's in a Dictionary or something like that?

I just don't know if this is an appropriate tasks for the Unit of Work to undertake. In examples in books and on blogs I haven't really seen this problem addressed yet.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Unit of work in and of itself doesn't preclude returning ids or objects.

The issue may be that you are using the using of work at too high a granularity, i.e. Creating  multiple objects who's ID's you may wish to capture in a single 'unit' (although in your example case, returning an order object that has a customerid would solve the problem). My advise would be to keep your units small, typically dealing with only 1 aggregate root.

In saying that, this is a real issue with patterns used with Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS), such as Event Sourcing.

There are two approaches to resolve the object ID's in this case: 
1. Have an 'object created' callback
2. give your transient objects guid id's and use an Identity Mapper to retrieve the created ID.

Hope this helps

Steven